# Return to previous window on click of 'Go to previous page' link

Tags: javascript, html

I have an **about** link on my **home** page on click of that link that it opens in a new browser tab. How can I go back to the previous page (home page) browser tab by closing the newly opened about page browser tab.

```
<a href="#" onclick="location.href = document.referrer; return false;">Go to previous page</a>
```

By using above code its going back to the previous page in new tab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use *window.close()* to close an opened tab.

Comment: This does not guarantee that the user will come back to its original page.